# Detectar cuando el usuario cierre la pagina

Tags: web, funciones, variables

¿Cómo puedo detectar si el usuario cierra mi pagina con JavaScript?.

He intentado con esto:

```
<body onbeforeunload="ConfirmClose()" onunload="HandleOnClose()">

 var myclose = false;

function ConfirmClose()
{
   if (event.clientY < 0)
   {
       event.returnValue = 'estas seguro?';
       setTimeout('myclose=false',10);
       myclose=true;
   }
 }

function HandleOnClose()
 {
   if (myclose==true) 
   {
       location.replace('/contextpath/j_spring_security_logout') ;
   }   
  }
```

Y no detecta si el usuario cierra la pagina

¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 1):

Los eventos `onunload` y `onbeforeunload` tiene que inicializarse con `window`, asi:

```
var myclose = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (event.clientY < 0)
  {
     event.returnValue = 'estas seguro?';
     setTimeout('myclose=false',10);
     myclose=true;
  }
};

window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  if (myclose==true) 
  {
     location.replace('/contextpath/j_spring_security_logout') ;
  } 
};
```

Te recomiendo leer [onload-ondomcontentloaded](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded) para entender mas sobre estos eventos